# Combine two files, replacing one field from file1 with another from file2

Tags: linux, sh, paste, cut

File1

```
ANK37748|DEL37728|SRILANKA|195210290000|201209111625
CHA38228|DEL37728|SRILANKA|198410290000|201308071912
ANK37748|DEL37728|SRILANKA|199910290000|201407061815
CHA38228|DEL37728|SRILANKA|199810290000|201507062212
```

File2

```
1952-Oct-29 12:00   
1984-Oct-29 12:00   
1999-Oct-29 12:00          
1998-Oct-29 12:00
```

Desired output

```
ANK37748|DEL37728|SRILANKA|1952-Oct-29 12:00|201209111625
CHA38228|DEL37728|SRILANKA|1984-Oct-29 12:00|201308071912
ANK37748|DEL37728|SRILANKA|1999-Oct-29 12:00|201407061815
CHA38228|DEL37728|SRILANKA|1998-Oct-29 12:00|201507062212
```

What didn't work:

```
paste file1 file2
```

Which output (1st line only):

```
ANK37748|DEL37728|SRILANKA|195210290000|201209111625 1952-Oct-29 12:00
```

I need to replace the fourth column of **file1** with the first (and only) column of **file2**.

Please help me.

Ben

Comment: What did you try, where are your problems?

Comment: paste filenew f11.txt

Comment: Hai,                                                                                                       $paste file1 file2                   output is ANK37748|DEL37728|SRILANKA|195210290000|201209111625     1952-Oct-29 12:00   etc i need to replace fourth column with the file2 column i don't know how to do it please help me

Answer (score 0):

Use **paste** and **cut**, setting the field separator to "|":

```
paste -d \| file[12]  file1 | cut -d \| -f '-3,6,11'
```

Output:

```
ANK37748|DEL37728|SRILANKA|1952-Oct-29 12:00|201209111625
CHA38228|DEL37728|SRILANKA|1984-Oct-29 12:00|201308071912
ANK37748|DEL37728|SRILANKA|1999-Oct-29 12:00|201407061815
CHA38228|DEL37728|SRILANKA|1998-Oct-29 12:00|201507062212
```

Note the kludge -- *cut*'s rude '-f' switch can output fields in order and skip fields, but like a paper teletype it can't back up!  Instead of something sensible like **cut -f '-3,6,5'**, *paste* needs to be passed 'file1' *twice*, hence the '11' field.

(The above job could be done kludgelessly in pure *Bourne shell*, *bash*, *awk*, *sed*, etc. or mixed combinations of those.)

Comment: Hai agc  Thank you very much